# Is there a way to count the number of words for each row in a specific excel column?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a .csv file saved as an object called "ProjectTwo" that has the following columns: "song", "artist", "year", "lyrics", with lyrics being the actual lyrics to the song. Here's a snapshot of what the dataset looks like:
[image]

I have taken the lyrics of every song and lemmatized the words to seperate them using nltk.

```
lyrics_all = ProjectTwo["lyrics"]
str1 = ''.join(lyrics_all)
nltk_tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(str1)
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer_results = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in nltk_tokenized]
print(lemmatizer_results)
```

Some results:

['I', "'m", 'crazy', 'for', 'my', 'baby', 'But', 'my', 'baby', 'she', 'do', "n't", 'love', 'me', 'I', "'m", 'so', 'lonely', 'babe', 'I', "'m", 'so', 'lonely', 'babe', 'No', 'I', 'ca', "n't", 'live', 'without', 'you', 'babe', 'I', "'m", 'so', 'lonely', 'babe', 'I', 'woke', 'up', 'last', ...]

I want to find a way to count every word to each song so that I can plot the length of songs (number of words) as a function of year and then add a regression line, but I can't figure out how to count the words of each song.

Comment: It's not an excel file.

Comment: Use [**`len`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the length: `len(lemmatizer_results)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a function that count the number of objects in a list it could be that:

```
def countNbrWords():
    count = 0
    for i in lemmatizer_results:
        count += 1
    print(count)
```